# Will the library be imported twice?

Tags: python

I am writing a python project. I am using a library (pandas) inside a module where my class is stored. Then I am importing this module to the main script. Then want use the same library inside my main script.

Will the library be imported twice? If yes, what are the performance side effects? How can I avoid them?

Comment: No, once it's loaded, it's cached and won't be loaded again. You can safely import it into any source file where you need it to be in scope without performance hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, once it's loaded, it's cached and won't be loaded again. You can safely import it into any source file where you need it to be in scope without performance hit.

Note that this is also relevant if you realise that when a module is first loaded, it is actually executed.

For example if you have `my_mod.py`:

```
def hello():
    print('hello')


print('loading')
```

And you use it from `main.py`:

```
import my_mod

input('waiting, press enter')
hello()
```

You'll notice that `loading` will be printed and then after you enter something `hello` gets printed. You can import the same file again from other modules, but `loading` won't be printed again, since the module doesn't get executed again, it just gets brought into scope for wherever you import it.